Setting JAVA_HOME does nothing in Linux
I have both java17 and java11 on my Debian12 PC and I would like to use java11 by default.
However, after setting JAVA_HOME, PATH and JRE_HOME successfully, My PC tells me I am still using java17 by default.

$ java -version

openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+9-Debian-1deb12u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+9-Debian-1deb12u1, mixed mode, sharing)

The setting I added in .bashrc:
# >>> java >>>
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
# <<< java <<<

Here is my terminal output
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/


$ echo $JRE_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64//jre

echo $PATH
/home/MYUSER/.vscode-server/bin/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/bin/remote-cli:/home/MYUSER/miniconda3/bin:/home/MYUSER/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/Users/someone/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/someone/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/opt/riscv/bin:/opt/riscv/bin:/home/MYUSER/apache-maven-3.9.7/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin


BTW PATH entries are used in the listed order, that is, if you want your entry to be used before others, it must be added before the others: PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH -- probably Java 17's path was already on the PATH

If you work at the command line I find this approach much easier: alias j22='export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java22-full-amd64;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not actually used by Java itself. It is a convention used by Java-based tools to find the JDK. And in Linux, generally there will be a symlink to the current Java in one of the bin folders that is earlier on your PATH.

Yes, that link will usually be /usr/bin/java. I personally have never found it necessary or even useful to define JRE_HOME

The first thing that I'd check is to run which java. When you know that, you can do an ls -l on the result. If it is a problem with $PATH, then user 85421's explanation points to the likely solution.

which java won't help you. All it will do is show you a link. You need readlink -f "$(which java)"

Default
find all JDK in your machine.
update-alternatives --config java

config
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1081
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1101

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac 1081
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac 1101

switch JDK
sudo update-alternatives --config java

OR INSTALL SDKMAN
Remove all JDK.
Install SDKMAN.
list all java
sdk list java

install JDK
sdk install java 11.0.23-tem
sdk install java 17.0.11-tem
sdk install java 22.0.1-oracle

switch JDK version
switch to Temurin JDK 17.0.11
sdk default java 17.0.11-tem

switch to Oracle JDK 22.0.1
sdk default java 22.0.1-oracle

Also can use sdkman install maven and kotlin and gradle.
You don't need to manual change JAVA_HOME, PATH in your profile. (.bashrc or other).
